# mongodb query won't aggregate and sort

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have a simple query that's giving me unexpected results when I query a public [mongodb server](https://steemdata.com/guide),

`mongodb://steemit:steemit@mongo1.steemdata.com:27017/SteemData`

```
db.getCollection('Posts')
.aggregate([
        { $match: { "created" : { $gte: ISODate("2017-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt: ISODate("2017-10-30T00:00:00.000Z") } } },
        { $group: { "_id": "author", "itemcount": { "$sum": 1 } } },
        { $sort: { "itemcount": -1 } }
])
```

I'm trying to get a count of the number of articles by author for the month of October.

I would hope to see a result set something like,

```
Bob 10
Joe  9
Sam  3
Tim  1
```

Instead I'm getting,

```
author 23
```

Can someone explain what's wrong with my aggregation pipeline?

Thanks

Comment: You are missing  $. Try "$author" for group id.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small issue with your group stage; the name of the field in the group stage ('author') should be prefixed with a dollar sign, like in [this example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#retrieve-distinct-values) in the documentation for $group.

Try updating the group stage to the following:

```
    { $group: { "_id": "$author", "itemcount": { "$sum": 1 } } },
```

Comment: If I do this, my script parses and executes but I get, `The script executed successfully, but there are no results to show.` Yet there must be results as without the `$` I get `author 473938.0`.

Comment: Can you update the question to include an example document? Also, how are you running this operation (e.g. the mongo shell, or something else)?

Comment: I won't be able to connect to your database; you should delete this comment as it is showing your username and password.

Comment: It’s a public access database.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's nothing to do with the query...

This one run at 5:32pm (ignore the single quotes, I tried with both)
[image]
And then a few mins later at 5:41pm
[image]